# Wolfram Alpha's solution to $\lim_{x\to 0+} \frac{\ln\ x}{x^2}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I was trying to compute the following:

$$\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{\ln x}{x^2}$$

And it stumped me after doing the following work:

Applied the product rule for limits:

$$\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{\ln x}{x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{1}{x^2}\bullet\lim_{x\to 0+} \ln x$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0+} \ln x = -\infty$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{\ln x}{x^2}= \lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{1}{x^2} \bullet -\infty$$

Now, for as to what to do here, I was stumped, and WolframAlpha did the following:

$$\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{1}{x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0+}e^{-2\ln x}$$

And then, to my confusion, did this:

$$\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{1}{x^2} = e^{\lim_{x\to 0+}-2\ln x}$$

And with that, proceeded to solve:

$$\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{1}{x^2} = e^{-2\  \bullet
\  -\infty}$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{1}{x^2} = \infty$$

For the final result:

$$\infty \bullet -\infty = -\infty$$

What I don't understand, however, is how

$$\lim_{x\to 0+}e^{-2\ln x} = e^{\lim_{x\to 0+}-2\ln x}$$

preserves equality. How is this justifiable? Is this always applicable?

Comment: The product rule for limits requires that the limits of each individual factor exist, and neither limits exist in your situation. As far as why it's justifiable, it is because of the continuity of $e^x$.  Here's a link that hopefully helps:https://gmumathclub.wordpress.com/2010/08/31/sequential-characterization-of-continuity-at-a-point-2/

Comment: This last formula is a sort of "continuity at infinity". It can be justified by using $\lim_{y \to \infty} e^y = +\infty$. I wouldn't recommend writing it this way though.

Comment: It's a nice illustration to the rule "shit in, shit out". If the question doesn't make sense, don't expect the answer to do so, especially if it comes from a program. It may be (artificially) intelligent, but not foolproof.

Comment: Formatting tip \ln gives proper spacing so instead of ln \ x it's better to write \ln x (at least that's my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\ln{x}}{x^2}$ is absurd, but
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\ln{x}}{x^2}=-\infty$$
because for $x\rightarrow0^+$ we have $\ln{x}\rightarrow-\infty$ by definition of $\ln$ and $\frac{1}{x^2}\rightarrow+\infty$.

Now we can use the definition of $\lim$ if you wish.

Comment: My apologies, my haste caused me to forgot it's from the right. How do I solve it though, without looking at the graph? I've edited it appropriately.

Comment: @sangstar I fixed my post. See now please.